# How to ensure nested arrays don't update in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

When I run this code in Ruby:

```
outerarr = []
innerarr = [1]
outerarr.push(innerarr)
innerarr[0] += 1
```

then outerarr will be [[2]].

I understand why this occurs, but is there a way of "disconnecting" innerarr, so to speak, so that when innerarr is updated outerarr does not change (i.e. remains as [[1]])?

Thanks.

Comment: Arrays are first class object. When one array(object) references another, and when reference changes state, it get's reflected. This is very basic rule of Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Do you want to keep `innerarr` to be changeable just `outerarr` should not change? Or do you want to ensure `innerarr` cannot be change anymore once it was pushed into `outerarr`? What is the expected output for `innerarr` and `outerarr` after running `innerarr[0] += 1`?

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you create a copy of original array. Eg
`outerarr.push(innerarr.dup)`